# Ruby on rails - No template found for InvitesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create an invitation system with rails 5 and mongoid. But when I want to sent an email i have this error :

```
Recipient can't be blank
something goes wrong
Recipient can't be blank
No template found for InvitesController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 137ms
```

Here is the code :

**invite.rb**

```
class Invite
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :email, type: String
  field :token, type: String

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :sender_id, :class_name => 'User', inverse_of: :recipient_id
  belongs_to :recipient_id, :class_name => 'User', inverse_of: :sender_id

  before_create :generate_token

  def generate_token
    self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([self.project_id, Time.now, rand].join)
  end
end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # Principle informations concerning project
  field :title, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :client, type: String
  field :deadline, type: String
  field :creator_id, type: String

  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User', inverse_of: :members
  has_many :members, :class_name => 'User', inverse_of: :owner
  has_many :invites
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise  :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  has_many :projects, inverse_of: :projects
  has_many :invitations, :class_name => 'Invite', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => 'Invite', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
end
```

the form for sending an invitation on the user page :

```
<%= form_for @invite do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :project_id, :value => @project.id %>
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email %>
            <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
        <% end %>
```

**invites_controller.rb**

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
    def new 
        @invite = Invite.new
    end

    def create 
        @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
        @invite.sender_id = current_user.id
        if @invite.save
            InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
            redirect_to user_path(current_user.id)
        else
            puts @invite.errors.full_messages
            puts "something goes wrong"
        end
        puts @invite.errors.full_messages
    end

    private
    def invite_params
        params.require(:invite).permit(:email, :token, :sender_id, :recipient_id, [:project_id])
    end 
end
```

I want that the owner be able to invite other people, if the user exist it send the mail to the existing user, but if not, it send a link to create an account and register in the project,

what I have forget ? And Why i have this error ?

Thank !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In create action, at the end you need to render a page or else you need to redirect the user to another page. For example, change your code like this:

```
def create 
        @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
        @invite.sender_id = current_user.id
        if @invite.save
            InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
            redirect_to user_path(current_user.id)
        else
            puts @invite.errors.full_messages
            puts "something goes wrong"
            redirect_to :back #OR render :new
        end

end
```

> Observe that I'm redirecting the user back, if saving the object fails(At the end of 'else' block)

If you want even better code, you should have something like this:

```
def create  
    @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
    @invite.sender_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invite.save
        format.html { redirect_to '/', notice: 'Invite was successfully created' }
        format.json { render :@invite.json }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @invite.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

> The above code handles both html and json requests

Answer (score 1):

By default, controllers in Rails automatically render views with names that correspond to method name. The `else` block in the create method doesn't have a response, so rails is looking for a view named as `create` to render. Put `render :new` in that block, so the `new` view will be re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Change your create method like this:

```
def create 
  @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
  @invite.sender_id = current_user.id
  if @invite.save
    InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
    redirect_to user_path(current_user.id)
  else
    puts @invite.errors.full_messages
    puts "something goes wrong"
    render :new
  end
end
```